Using Docker APIs (golang), I am able to have all log result displayed in my terminal, except for the one was generated by unittest
Unable to retrieve unittest log while using Docker API for GOLANG.
Official Document for this API: (https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/)
I can retrieve all log of "fmt.Print" function but not the log from the unittest.
Why is this happen ? and how do we store the unittest log into a vriable ?
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
    "github.com/docker/docker/pkg/stdcopy"
)

func main() {
    userCode := `
def two_sum(nums, target):
    num_dict = {}
    for i, num in enumerate(nums):
        complement = target - num
        if complement in num_dict:
            return [num_dict[complement], i]
        num_dict[num] = i
    return []
    `

    // Predefined test cases
    testCode := `
import unittest
from main import two_sum

class TestTwoSum(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(two_sum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9), [0, 1])

    def test_case_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(two_sum([3, 2, 4], 6), [1, 2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
`
    //ctx := context.Background()
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer cli.Close()

    // 1. Create 2 temp files
    hostWorkingDir, err := os.MkdirTemp("", "")
    check(err)
    fmt.Println("Temp dir name:", hostWorkingDir)
    defer os.RemoveAll(hostWorkingDir)

    codeFilePath := filepath.Join(hostWorkingDir, "main.py")
    codeFile, err := os.Create(codeFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to create source file", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Code file name:", codeFile.Name())
    defer codeFile.Close()

    testFilePath := filepath.Join(hostWorkingDir, "test.py")
    testFile, err := os.Create(testFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to create test file", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Test file name:", testFile.Name())
    defer testFile.Close()

    // 2. Write code into 2 temp files:
    _, err = codeFile.WriteString(userCode)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("failed to write source file")
        return
    }

    _, err = testFile.WriteString(testCode)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("failed to write test file")
        return
    }

    // 3. Create Container
    ctx := context.Background()

    workingDir := "/work"
    programFileDirectory, codePath := filepath.Split(codeFile.Name())
    _, testPath := filepath.Split(testFile.Name())
    codePath = filepath.Join(workingDir, codePath)
    fmt.Println(codePath)
    testPath = filepath.Join(workingDir, testPath)
    fmt.Println(testPath)
    resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image:        "docker.io/library/python:3.13-rc-slim",
        Cmd:          []string{"timeout", "--foreground", "10s", "python", "test.py"},
        WorkingDir:   workingDir,
        AttachStdin:  true,
        AttachStdout: true,
        AttachStderr: true,
        OpenStdin:    true,
        StdinOnce:    true,
    }, &container.HostConfig{
        Binds: []string{fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", programFileDirectory, workingDir)},
        Resources: container.Resources{
            CPUQuota: 1000000,
            Memory:   int64(256 * 1024 * 1024), /// 256 MB
        },

        NetworkMode: "none"}, nil, nil, "")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //4. Start Container
    if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, container.StartOptions{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //5. Wait for container to response
    statusCh, errCh := cli.ContainerWait(ctx, resp.ID, container.WaitConditionNotRunning)
    select {
    case err := <-errCh:
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    case <-statusCh:

    }
    out, err := cli.ContainerLogs(ctx, resp.ID, container.LogsOptions{ShowStdout: true})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    stdcopy.StdCopy(os.Stdout, os.Stderr, out)
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}


Is the unittest output on stderr? It looks like you're only retrieving the container's stdout at the end.

@DavidMaze , you're right !!!.  The unittest output is on stderr, so I need to add the stderr to my container.logOptions and it works perfectly. Thank you.
